oidc-provider npm: How to add custom claims to jwt token
I am developing an OIDC solution using the oidc-provider npm and authorization code request with PKCE.  I am able to login and exchange the auth code for the access token and id token but I need to add role determining information to the token so the UI can morph depending upon different values.  I saw there also is a /me endpoint as well, not sure if that is where this should be handled.  Either way, I need to be able to dictate which fields go into the jwt.  Where would I do this using oidc-provider?
